# Laravel 5.1 sort a table

Tags: php, sorting, laravel, eloquent

I have a simple controller function to output a table of users, but I want it to sort by the 'approved' column, which is either 1 or 0. My controller looks like this:

```
public function showAllUsers()
{
    $users = \User::all();
    return \View::make('admin.users.all', array('users' => $users));
}
```

How do I sort the table by this column? I have tried functions like `SortBy('approved','desc')` but this doesn't have an effect.

**View:***

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/datatables.js"></script>
@stop

@section('stylesheets')
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('css/datatables.css')}}" />
@stop

    @section('content')
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Members</h1>
                    @if(Session::has('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <p>{{ 

Session::get('success') }}</p>
                    </div>
                @endif

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="{{url('admin/members/add')}}">Add Member</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table id="dattab" class="table table-hover table-striped tablesorter">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="header headerSortUp">Membership ID <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                    <th class="header">Fullname <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                    <th class="header">Membership Type <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                    <th class="header">Status<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                    <th class="header">Join Date<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                    <th class="header">Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$user->membership_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->firstname." ".$user->lastname}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->getMembershipType()}}</td>
                    <td>
                        @if($user->approved) Approved
                        @elseif (!$user->approved)
                            <a href="{{url('admin/members/approve/'.$user->id)}}" class="btn btn-success">Approve</a>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ (new DateTime($user->created_at))->format('d/m/Y') }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Choose Action <span class="caret"></span>
                          </button>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="{{url('admin/members/edit/'.$user->id)}}">Edit</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="{{url('admin/members/delete/'.$user->id)}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure');">Delete</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>                  
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div><!-- /.row -->


@stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query builder to get the database to order the results before they're retrieved. See the docs for more information http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

```
public function showAllUsers()
{
    $users = \User::orderBy('approved', 'desc')->get();

    return view('admin.users.all', compact('users'));
}
```

Alternativly you can also sort them after they've been retrieved from the database using the laravel collections. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sortby

```
public function showAllUsers()
{
    $users = \User::all()->sortBy('approved', 'desc');

    return view('admin.users.all', compact('users'));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to affect the table at all. Is there a way I can check the contents of the table before it is displayed on the view?

Comment: use `dd($users)` before you return the view. What order are you expecting the results in? How are you displaying the results in your view? `'desc'` will order the results from 1 -> 0, `'asc`' will order results from 0 -> 1.

Comment: I want it to display the 0's first. The table returns the correct order, but it doesn't display the table in that order. It always displays in the ID order ascending, so perhaps that's been coded in somewhere

Comment: How are you displaying the results in your view? Can you edit your question and include the code for your view, sounds like you're doing something there that is adjusting the ordering.

Comment: Huh, odd. Is datatable being applied to the table? If so try removing and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Removing datatables seems to have worked. I'll have to try and find a way to remove the default sorter in this table. Ill mark this answer as correct. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Yeh. if you're using datatables, then no need to sort via. a query. Setting the default sorting for datatables looks pretty easy, https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll be looking for the orderBy method: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

In this case:

```
$users = \User::orderBy('approved','desc')->get();
```